# Angular Installation problems and permissions fail on Mac why?

Tags: macos, npm, permissions, installation, angular-cli

It's the first time using Angular. I check I had the required node version, but I will get permission errors and I am not sure why? I am using a mac and I am getting permission failures or rejection errors. I also tried sudo npm install -g @angular/cli. Any guesses? Because I don't know what to do.

```
stephaniegalindo@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install -g @angular/cli     
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular
npm ERR! path /Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli'

npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm/_logs/2019-12-12T06_21_07_335Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having permission issues in your `~/.npm-global` directory.

First check in your home directory if **.npm-global** folder exists.

If it's there try these commands.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm-global
```

And try installing Angular again.

If you don't have the **.npm-global** folder, I suggest you reinstall npm with a node version manager.

Comment: stephaniegalindo@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
Password:
stephaniegalindo@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo npm install -g @angular/cli 
/Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@8.3.20 postinstall /Users/stephaniegalindo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@8.3.20
updated 2 packages in 103.863s this is what was added but say that ng is not a command

Comment: It seems you don't have the path setup to ng. 
Check if you have **ng** installed under `~/.nvm/versions/node/$(node --version)/bin`. 
If you do have **ng**. Try adding this line to your **~/.bashrc** file. 
`export PATH=~/.nvm/versions/node/$(node --version)/bin:$PATH` 
Then run `source ~/.bashrc`. Then try installing angular again.